# Не рисуют изображения canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Имею следующий **код** :

```
    for(var i = 0; parseInt(canvas.width / blockSize) > i; i++) {
      console.log('Кря');
      GetImageToCanvas('grassGame.png', function(image) {
        console.log('load image');
        console.log('image : ' + image);
        console.log(c.drawImage(image, (i == 0) ? blockSize :  blockSize*i, 0, blockSize, blockSize));
      });
    }

    function GetImageToCanvas(img, cb) {    
      var image = new Image();
      image.src='images/'+img;
      image.onload=function(){
        cb(image);
      };
    }
```

Проблема в том, что рисует лишь последнее изображение.

Answer (score 0):

Вам просто не нужно создавать каждый раз новое изображение при вызове функции рисования. Вот небольшой пример отрисовки изображения циклом([разбор этого примера](https://habrahabr.ru/post/111385/)). Если вы разрабатываете какую либо игру, лучше используйте фреймворки, типа [Pixi](http://www.pixijs.com/) или [Phaser](http://phaser.io/).

```js
var example = document.getElementById("example"),
    ctx = example.getContext('2d'),
    cellSize = 32,
    pic = new Image(),
    map = 
    [
      [{x:1,y:4},{x:1,y:4},{x:1,y:4},{x:1,y:4},{x:1,y:4},{x:1,y:4},{x:1,y:4},{x:1,y:4}],
      [{x:1,y:4},{x:1,y:1},{x:2,y:1},{x:3,y:1},{x:1,y:4},{x:1,y:4},{x:1,y:4},{x:1,y:4}],
      [{x:1,y:4},{x:1,y:2},{x:2,y:2},{x:3,y:2},{x:1,y:4},{x:1,y:3},{x:1,y:3},{x:1,y:3}],
      [{x:1,y:4},{x:3,y:4},{x:2,y:3},{x:3,y:4},{x:1,y:4},{x:1,y:3},{x:1,y:4},{x:1,y:4}],
      [{x:1,y:4},{x:3,y:4},{x:2,y:4},{x:3,y:4},{x:1,y:4},{x:1,y:3},{x:1,y:4},{x:1,y:4}],
      [{x:1,y:4},{x:1,y:4},{x:1,y:3},{x:1,y:4},{x:1,y:4},{x:1,y:3},{x:1,y:4},{x:1,y:4}],
      [{x:1,y:4},{x:1,y:4},{x:1,y:3},{x:1,y:3},{x:1,y:3},{x:1,y:3},{x:1,y:4},{x:1,y:4}],
      [{x:1,y:4},{x:1,y:4},{x:1,y:4},{x:1,y:4},{x:1,y:4},{x:1,y:4},{x:1,y:4},{x:1,y:4}]
    ];
example.width = 8 * cellSize;
example.height = 8 * cellSize;
pic.src = 'http://habr.habrastorage.org/post_images/e85/727/cb1/e85727cb1a88099325eaf5b243d4c41f.png';
pic.onload = function () {
    for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            ctx.drawImage(pic, (map[i][j].x - 1) * cellSize, (map[i][j].y - 1) * cellSize, 32, 32, j * cellSize, i * cellSize, 32, 32);
        }
    }
}
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<canvas id='example'></canvas>
```